# How to update null values to 0, for rows not exists in joined table?

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables.

```
requests
id|code|count|


oldrequests
id|code|count|
```

I need to update *count* in *requests* from *oldrequests*. The main problem that I'm trying to update NULL *count* values with coalesce(oldrequests.count,0) like this:

```
update request req
set count = coalesce(oldreq.count,0)
from oldrequests oldreq
where req.code = oldreq.code
```

But NULL values from *requests* not updating.
Then I tried to set NULL values to 0, like this:

```
update request req
set count = 0
from oldrequests oldreq
where req.code = oldreq.code and oldreq.id is null
```

But this didn't help me too.
How can I update values and NULL values?

Comment: What is the data type of count and code field?

Comment: code varchar, count integer

Comment: That's why I'm using coalesce.

Comment: My question is whether `code` is also `null` or only `count` is `null`? Because your first query is not having any problem and in second query you have written `oldreq.id is null` why you are checking null for `ID`

Comment: That condition worked well when I used this in case expression in SELECT, but now I don't know how to use this logic in UPDATE. For example: 'Case when oldrequest.id is null then count = 0 end'.

Answer (score 1):

I mean the problem is update count for rows have not matches in `oldrequests` table. I can advice next approach to solve it:

Update all counts in `requests` table by `0` and after update matches rows count from `oldrequests` table like:

```
update requests set count = 0;

update requests req
set count = coalesce(oldreq.count,0)
from oldrequests oldreq
where req.code = oldreq.code;
```

Another approach is set `0` on ly for not matched rows:

```
update requests set count = 0
where (select code from oldrequests where oldrequests.code = requests.code) is null;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=66e2968f57c97154ff8e34a83ed37794)

or another version using `not exist` clause:

```
update requests set count = 0
where not exists (
    select code from oldrequests where oldrequests.code = requests.code
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8ce71c4dfb09b516d724e30a4668247f)